# How can I change my textblock's multiline to have different text alignments

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, multiline, textblock

How could I change each of my textblock's lines to have different alignments? So far I have this code but I don't know how to change the second and third ones.

```
<TextBlock Margin="0" Foreground="Red" TextAlignment="Left">
    <Run Text="First Line (Left)"/><LineBreak />
    <Run Text="Second Line (Center)"/><LineBreak />
    <Run Text="Third Line (Right)"/><LineBreak />         
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce a similar outcome however you will have multiple TextBlocks:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="First Line (Left)" Margin="0" Foreground="Red" TextAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Second Line (Center)" Margin="0" Foreground="Red" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Third Line (Right)" Margin="0" Foreground="Red" TextAlignment="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```